# Snap over 250 images to one image per cell

Tags: image, vba, excel

I am working on a spreadsheet at work and a coworker pasted over 250 images ontop of a column. The images are not snapped to the cells they correspond to, so any manipulation of the cells causes to images to be in the wrong place.

I am looking for a way to paste all the images into cells, and have them be a part of the cell, just as if I were pasting a list of text.

In an ideal world I would hope it would work like this:

1. Place all images in an array
2. using the key number of the image in the array, assign it to a corresponding cell number
3. Parse the dimensions of the corresponding cell, and apply the dimensions to the image

This is what I have tried:

```
Sub movePics()
  Dim picCounter As Long

  picCounter = 0
  For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    picCounter = picCounter + 1
    With s
      .Left = 100
      .Top = ActiveSheet.Rows(picCounter).Top
      .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In an ideal world I would hope it would work like this: 1. Place all images in an array 2. using the key number of the image in the array, assign it to a corresponding cell number 3. Parse the dimensions of the corresponding cell, and apply the dimensions to the image.

Comment: You'll receive a lot more help if you show us what you've tried to accomplish this. SO is not a "code for me" site. You have the steps, now write the code and post back where you get stuck on any steps.

Comment: See edit, added what I have tried.

Comment: unfortunately I only have the images in the clipboard, and not as individual files.

Answer (score 0):

This quick loop will move through all shapes and set them to "Move and Size with Cells".

```
Sub Testing()

    For x = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(x).Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    Next x

End Sub
```